# How is Code analysis CA1702:CompoundWordsShouldBeCasedCorrectly implemented

Tags: c#, static-code-analysis

How is the rule implemented?

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264474.aspx) it says

> The name of the identifier is split into words that are based on the casing. Each contiguous two-word combination is checked by the Microsoft spelling checker library. If it is recognized, the identifier produces a violation of the rule. Examples of compound words that cause a violation are "CheckSum" and "MultiPart", which should be cased as "Checksum" and "Multipart", respectively.

How is this rule implemented, is there a dictionary of disallowed multipart words, or some other complex logic?

Comment: "Each contiguous two-word combination is checked by the Microsoft spelling checker library." So the answer is that it uses the spelling checker library, probably the same one you get in Microsoft Word.

Comment: You can check the [Roslyn Analyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers) repo on Github directly. Text analyzers [are here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/tree/master/src/Text.Analyzers). Finding the implementation is a bit harder though - a *lot* of rules depend on word splitting spelling etc. A lot of helper/utility classes can be found in the [Utilities](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/tree/master/src/Utilities) folder, including a [WordParser](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/master/src/Utilities/WordParser.cs) class